# Exporting data to Excel in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I developed an application in Joomla. I used Fabrik for entering and retrieving data and database management. In Fabrik we have options to export to CSV and to Excel, but both are generating CSV file.

I strictly want Excel format. Where should I make change in Fabrik files and folders to generate Excel? Is there any other option? If not, I'd like to create a link that will generate Excel from data already saved through Fabrik.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting your research at the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org) (JED).  They have many open-source solutions, including some very good Excel solutions.

We'd love to help you, but simply stating what you've got and what you want is not enough for anyone to seriously spend time on.  If you supply specifics of what you have looked at in Joomla, or samples of that you're trying to change, you'll likely get more attention to your question.